Continuity of perimeter with respect to metric
Let $\Omega$ be an open set in a closed manifold, $(M^n, g)$. We can define the perimeter as
$$\text{Per}_g(\Omega) = \sup\bigg\{\int_{\Omega} \text{div}_g(T) dVol_g, \; : \; T \in C^1(M, T M), \quad \sup_{x \in \Omega} |T(x)| \leq 1\bigg\}$$
i.e. the supremum of the integrals of the divergence of all vectors fields on $M$, restricted to $\Omega$. I'd like to show that $\text{Per}(\Omega)$ is continuous with respect to the metric, i.e. if $g, g'$ are two smooth metrics on $M^n$, then
$$|\text{Per}_g(\Omega) - \text{Per}_{g'}(\Omega)| \leq K \|g - g'\|_{C^1}$$
Its okay if $K$ depends on $\Omega$. I guess the main difficulty I foresee is that changing the metric may create an error term depending on derivatives of the vector field. So its unclear how to handle these.

Have you tried writing it all out in local coordinates?

For some reason, this really didn't occur to me! Thanks

Unfortunately, that's not surprising. The emphasis these days is on coordinate-free calculations, so it doesn't occur to students to just use coordinates. My comment above is probably the most common I make on math.stackexchange.com.

@DeaneYang it seems that local coordinates is useful, but there's still a volume term to handle - if you have any further insight.

The square root of the determinant of a matrix is a continuous function of the matrix.

There's still $C^1$ dependence on the vector field in the error term, no? As written out in the edit of the answer below

@JMK, I assume you would be fine with some other quantitative bound, not necessarily Lipschitz?

@NateRiver Yeah for sure, as long as it gives continuity of perimeter in some category of regularity on the space of metrics, all good

I think that we can get Hölder dependence for small values of $|g - g'|_{C^1}$, but large values are a problem if you want a global constant. Would restricting to small values be okay?

The issue of course, is if you allow arbitrarily large perturbations, then @OrangeMushroom's example shows that no finite constant $K$ suffices.

@NateRiver, sure let's consider small values of $||g - g'||_{C^1}$, I guess the statement I want overall is that perimeter is continuous w.r.t. the metric, so it suffices to get a bound for small perturbations. I see that I wasn't rigorous enough with the scaling of the volume factor anyway

Let’s just try for continuity then.

As Deane Yang suggested, local coordinates is the way to go. In an arbitrary coordinate system
$$X = X^i \partial_i, \qquad \text{div}_g(X) = X^i_i + X^i \Gamma_{ki}^i(g)$$
$$\implies \text{div}_g(X) - \text{div}_{g'}(X) = X^i (\Gamma_{ki}^i(g) - \Gamma_{ki}^i(g'))$$
where my convention is that $\Gamma_{ki}^j = g^{j \ell} g(\nabla_{\partial k} \partial_i, \partial_{\ell})$. So if $\Omega$ is say compact, then using that $\|X\|_{L^{\infty}} \leq 1$, we have
$$\Big|\int_{\Omega} \text{div}_g(X) - \int_{\Omega} \text{div}_{g'}(X)\Big| \leq \text{Vol}_g(\Omega) \cdot K \|g - g'\|_{C^1}$$
Taking a sequence $X_i$ such that $\text{Per}_g(\Omega) = \lim_i \int_{\Omega} \text{div}_g(X_i)$, then readily shows that
$$\text{Per}_g(\Omega) \leq \text{Per}_{g'}(\Omega) + \text{Vol}_g(\Omega) \cdot K \|g - g'\|_{C^1}$$
EDIT: Actually I was too quick to conclude. To be really careful, we have
$$\int_{\Omega} \text{div}_g(X) dV_g - \int_{\Omega} \text{div}_{g'}(X) dV_{g'} = \int_{\Omega} (\text{div}_g(X) - \text{div}_{g'}(X)) dV_g + \int_{\Omega} \text{div}_{g'}(X) (dV_g - dV_{g'})$$
The first integral is boundable as before. Its tempting to say that
$$\Big| \int_{\Omega} \text{div}_{g'}(X) (dV_g - dV_{g'})\Big| \leq \|g - g'\|_{C^0}\cdot\int_{\Omega} |\text{div}_{g'}(X)|dV_g $$
But a priori, $\int_{\Omega} |\text{div}_{g'}(X)| dV_g$ could be very large!

@OrangeMushroom also a good point. There are many parts to the full proof that are still missing it seems.

You can write $dV_g' = f dV_g$ where $f\to 1$ in $C^1$. Then $div_g(X)(f-1) dV_g = div_G(X(f-1))dV_g - gX,\nabla (f-1))dV_g$. The first term integrated on $\Omega$ is $o(1)$ since $|X(f-1)| \to 0$ in $C^0$ and then the second is also $o(1)$ since $f\to 1$ in $C^1$ and $|X|\leq 1$. The issue raised by @OrangeMushroom can be fixed by shrinking $X$ a bit to compensate for the fact that $g'$ is measuring things slightly bigger/smaller than $g$ (but this stretch factor is $1+o(1)$ so goes away.

Oh clever! I guess your saying
$$|\int_{\Omega} \text{div}g(X(f-1)) dV_g| \leq ||X(f-1)||{C^0} |\int_{\Omega} \text{div}g \left(\frac{X(f-1)}{||X(f-1)||{C^0}} \right) dV_g | \leq ||X(f-1)|| Per_g(\Omega) \leq ||f-1|| Per_g(\Omega)$$
I think this is the step I was missing - thanks!
